# How to ignore the HTML components while retrieving the user profile data in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: development, user-profile

I am using a powershell script to retrieve the user profile information (i.e., about me, skills...)

```
$usp["sps-skills"].tostring()
```

It is getting the required information however the data also contains the unwanted HTML components (i.e, `<p>`,`<div>`...).

I want to escape the HTML components, what would be the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -replace parameter in Powershell, which works like Regex.Replace() in .NET.

```
$usp["sps-skills"].tostring() -replace "<(.|\n)*?>",""
```

matches 0 or more occurrances of any character or new line in between < and >